# ¿Obtener elementos de un renderer tras cargar una pagina html?

Tags: javascript, html

Si yo tengo una pagina html, que añado cosas con renderers e intento acceder a un formulario de un renderer(con querySelector por ejemplo) ¿Porque no me coge ese formulario? Me dice que es null.
Para cargar el htmo uso `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", main);` y el main es donde cargo el renderer.
Mis renderers son muys sencillos, pero dentro de ellos como he dicho tengo formularios a los que quiero acceder.
Mi html en el body solo tiene una navbar.
Y no es solo que no pueda acceder al formulario sino a cualquier otro elemento: div, button ...

Comment: Perdonad si no me explico bien pero llevo poco tiempo usando html y javascript

Comment: Crea un pequeño ejemplo de tu código que demuestre el problema que te encuentras, que contenga lo mínimo necesario para mostrarlo y que lo podamos probar y analizar. [Aquí](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) tienes información sobre cómo insertar el código de ejemplo en tu pregunta. También hay enlaces a *fiddles* que te ayudarán a probarlo.

Comment: @V.Lorz he visto el link pero me es un poco dificil. Le comento: yo tengo un documento html con una navbar solo. Con javascript creo un renderer que tiene una foto, descripción ... y una caja de comentarios. La caja de comentarios tiene un formulario con un textarea y un boton de submit. El renderer lo añado al codigo html con un  `appendChild(renderer)`. Y yo ahora quiero acceder al formulario una vez cargada la pagina para coger el texto del textarea y madarlo a la base de datos cuando le doy al boton submit. Pues si yo accedo al form con un querySelector(por ejemplo) pues me dice null.

Comment: @V.Lorz ...sigo por aqui--- El archivo js donde pongo que recoga el texto del textarea tiene una funcion main donde le digo que si pulsa el boton `formComment.onsubmit = handleSubmitComment`, y handleSubmitComment es la función que se encarga de recoger el evento y enviar datos. Este archivo js tiene abajo del todo lo siguiente: `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", main);` que es lo que creo que da problemas. Y no es solo que no pueda acceder al formulario sino a nada dentro del renderer porque como no esta en el html me dice el navegador que es null.

Comment: @V.Lorz En el documento html cargo el script que renderiza toda la información y tambien cargo otro script con el codigo que recoge los datos del textare. Ambos los cargo en el head.

Comment: Sin un ejemplo sencillo del código, uno aunque sea simple, no podremos ayudarte.  Te será útil darle una lectura a [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).